Meaning of "...projects already in train."
From this article: https://www.ft.com/content/ca441a61-6feb-4d94-970a-b83b75b8dcd0
"Tim Balcon, chief executive of the Construction Industry Training Board (CITB), estimates 250,000 new workers are required to deliver projects that are already in train."
I can confidently guess it means projects already underway. But I've never heard the expression "in train" before. Is my hunch correct about its meaning and can somebody explain to me the origins of this expression? Thanks.

Google explains in train:

phrase of train
(of arrangements) well organized or in progress.
"an investigation is in train"

So you've analysed correctly. Your example projects that are already in train means projects that are
in progress.
